# Can we use a font in iOS 6 if it's not included in iOS 5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, fonts, ios6

I would like to use the font "Avenir" which is included in iOS 6. Does that mean a device running iOS 5 won't be able to see the font? If so, is there a way to fallback on a different font if "Avenir" isn't available on their device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose the font you want to be used in iOS < 6 and assign it if necessary. Define a macro like this:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)      
       ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
```

and then you can do in your code:

```
NSString *fontName = @"Avenir";

if SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(6.0) { 
   fontName = @"ArialMT";
}
```

You can find a list of supported fonts here: http://iosfonts.com/

Comment: Why bother checking iOS versions? Try the first font. If you get a `nil` `UIFont` then fallback to the other font. This will make the app a bit more future proof too.

Comment: What happens to fonts assigned using Storyboards/Interface Builder? I can see that Avenir is included in the list. Any ideas about what'd happen on iOS5?

Comment: @Ben Clayton One can use a Font available with iOS 6.0, in case the font is not available with lower versions of iOS i.e. iOS<6.0 it will use a system default font i.e.Helvetica.