# How can I use iOS6 fonts in iOS5

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, fonts, typeface

My app uses the lovely Avenir font which is built in to iOS6 but not iOS5. How can I get it onto iOS5? I know I can fall back to a different font on iOS5 (eg just use System font) but I don't want to do that. Can I build the Avenir font into my app some how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13435170/1059705 might help you ..

Comment: Thanks, but I saw that and I don't want to fall back to another font, I want to use Avenir on iOS5. A font is just data so how can I get a copy and build it into my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No and Yes, you could just supply the font with your app. 
But you will need to buy a distribution license for the font, this will be very costly.

Your best option is to fall back to an other font on iOS5 or just not support iOS5.

Comment: Thanks but how costly and where can I buy it?

Comment: http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/avenir/ has some options to buy it. it's about 260 per type. Also keep im mind that after iOS 7 is release you will have to drop iOS5 support and currently iOS is only about 4% of the total iOS user (+95% are already on iOS 6).

Comment: Ok, interesting. Why will I have to drop iOS5 when iOS7 is released? I have been planning on supporting iOS5, iOS6 and iOS7.

Comment: Well because of the dynamic font size in iOS7 you will need to user Autolayout for all your views, labels and buttons. Since Autolayout is only available on iOS 6 and higher you will want to drop iOS 5 support. Also why put so much effort in support an OS that less then 2% of you user will user. You budget for support iOS 5 will be more then 2% of the total budget of you app then it is not worth the time.